# Default value of ACLs mask

Tags: linux, access-control, unix

This is the question I faced in an interview as a system administrator.

> If we didn't set the mask value, what is the default value of mask?

I was thinking that if we didn't set the mask, it should be the `rwx`, right?

For example:

```
> touch testfile
> getfacl testfile
# file: testfile
# owner: chenicha
# group: csgrad
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Even if it didn't state the status of mask, but I assume it should be `rwx`, right?

Comment: BTW, since this question involves information security and Linux. I am not sure this is the correct place I ask.

Comment: If a child process (like a shell) is created the umask is inherited from the parent process. And many shell profiles set the umask. So what umask you have if you don't explicitly set one depends on your current context and maybe also the specific setup of your system (which might depend on the vendor or your local administrator). Maybe your question is missing context to answer?

Comment: Yeah, I am actually not familiar with all of the steps. That makes the interview a little bit awkward. So the default mask will be determined by the current user who create the file?

Comment: The current umask depends on the  environment of the user. It is often set in the rc files when logging in. For example normal users often have a umask of 002 set in their shell so that the data can be shared within the group. system users instead often have the more restrictive 022. But the systems might also be setup differently.

Comment: How about you answer the question and give some example? I will pick you as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't apply any kind of `ACL` then there will be no need for a `mask`. According to the [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html%20%22this),

> The mask entry is automatically created when needed but not provided.

And according to [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html%20%22this) if you use minimal `ACL` then no mask will be added.

```
 [arif@arif blabla]$ ls -ldha .
 drwxrwxr-x. 2 arif arif 4.0K Oct 17 06:13 .
 [arif@arif blabla]$ getfacl --omit-header .
 user::rwx
 group::rwx
 other::r-x

[arif@arif blabla]$ chmod g-wx .
[arif@arif blabla]$ getfacl --omit-header .
user::rwx
group::r--
other::r-x

[arif@arif blabla]$ setfacl -m g::rw .
[arif@arif blabla]$ getfacl --omit-header .
user::rwx
group::rw-
other::r--
```

According to [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html%20%22this),

> Extended ACLs also contain a mask entry and may contain any number of named user and named group entries.

So now, we will use extended `ACL` which results `group class` permissions mapped to the `mask` entry because as mentioned [here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html%20%22this),

> In minimal ACLs, the group class permissions are identical to the owning group permissions. In extended ACLs, the group class may contain entries for additional users or groups. This results in a problem: some of these additional entries may contain permissions that are not contained in the owning group entry, so the owning group entry permissions may differ from the group class permissions.
>
> This problem is solved by the virtue of the mask entry. With minimal ACLs, the group class permissions map to the owning group entry permissions. With extended ACLs, the group class permissions map to the mask entry permissions, whereas the owning group entry still defines the owning group permissions.

```
[arif@arif blabla]$ setfacl -m g:wheel:rw .
[arif@arif blabla]$ getfacl --omit-header .
user::rwx
group::rw-
group:wheel:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Here, you can see that the value of group class permission is mapped to the `mask` despite of defining any specific `mask`. And this mapping approach ensures the smooth interaction of applications, regardless of whether they have ACL support. The reason for using `group class permission` bits as `mask` is described in the [TRUSIX documentation](https://fas.org/irp/nsa/rainbow/tg020-a.htm#HDR6.6%203%2030) as follows,

> The file group class permission bits are the preferred masking field, even though they encourage permissive default access by the owning group. This choice must be made because the use of the file owner class would cause compatibility problems in programs which attempt to establish "owner-only" access, whereas the designation of the file other class could leave objects open to attack were an ACL removed or never present. An additional option of masking user entries with the file owner class permission bits and group entries with the file group class permission bits has the same disadvantages as masking against only the file owner class.

So I believe you could have said that the default value of `mask` is same as the `group class` permission value.

Answer (score 0):

If no mask exists, Linux by default sets all folders to 777 and all files to 666. The 6's are to prevent files from being executed providing a bare minimum amount of security, whereas the 777 on directories allows them to be traversed. I don't think he was asking about ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

### Default file permission and ACL

Basically when creating an entry, default `mask` is

- `0666`  for files, as a file won't be *executable* by default and
- `0777`  for directories. (*execute* permission let you acces file and directories under one directory, even is you could not read them)

#### Understanding `umask` concept

About *security* concern, `umask` is used to define default permission when user create new entries in filesystem.

```
umask
0022
```

This *parameter* depend on installation and is often configured in `.bashrc`, `.shrc`, `.kshrc` or `.profile` user file., if not already in `/etc`.

```
umask 0077
```

By using this, every file or directories you will create will not be accessible by anyone but the owner:

```
mkdir test
# file: test
# owner: theuser
# group: theuser
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

Read: `man umask`, `man mkdir`, `man chmod`

### Inherit from parent

Under linux and before using `ACL` features, you could use `setgid` and `setuid` bits. This could force group owner or owner for new entries:

```
chmod 2773 test
su nobody -s /bin/sh -c 'echo "Hello world." >test/nobodyfile'
```

But

```
su nobody -s /bin/sh -c 'ls test'
ls: cannot open directory 'test': Permission denied
```

Anyway:

```
ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody theuser 13 29 oct 16:19 nobodyfile
```

The file is there, but the *group owner* is the same than *group owner* of parent.

Read: `man setuid`, `man setgid`

### Inherit ACL from parent

If some directory had `ACL` set, then previous consideration will be ignored, but `default` behaviours for entries that will be created under is directly configured:

```
# file: test
# owner: theuser
# group: theuser
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::-wx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx  #effective:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

Read: `man acl`, `man setfacl`, `man getfacl`